# can't copy database phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

When I try to copy a database within phpmyadmin it is not copying the data and I get an error without a number or a useful message.
Could the database be too large?
cPanel says it is 1071.72 MB
Other databases which are smaller copy ok
message is:

```
SQL query: 
CREATE DATABASE `buzz50_test5` ;
ALTER DATABASE `buzz50_test5` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

MySQL said:

[image]

Comment: Neither of those commands copy the database, so size is not the issue. What happens if you try to run those commands in the phpMyAdmin free form SQL window?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: Thanks for your replies Steve & Marc. My solution was to delete a stored procedure which was in the database and then it copied as expected.